# How to check if a given list is divisible by 4 in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to check if a given list of numbers(all of them) are divisible by 4

```
(divisible4 '(4,12,20))
#t

(divisible4 '(12 5 13))
#f
```

I have written this but it does not return #f. How can i fix this

```
(define (div2? list)
  (if (= (modulo (car list) 4) 0)
      #t
      (div2? cdr list)))
```

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code, and the standard template for traversing and processing a list is nowhere to be seen. You should spend more time learning the basic syntax of Scheme, before tackling harder exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to use built-ins, such as `andmap` that checks whether a condition holds for all elements in a list:

```
(define (divisible4 lst)
  (andmap (lambda (e) (zero? (modulo e 4)))
          lst))
```

We can do the same process by hand, albeit less elegantly:

```
(define (divisible4 lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #t
      (and (zero? (modulo (car lst) 4))
           (divisible4 (cdr lst)))))
```

Equivalently:

```
(define (divisible4 lst)
  (or (null? lst)
      (and (zero? (modulo (car lst) 4))
           (divisible4 (cdr lst)))))
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
(divisible4 '(4 12 20))
=> #t
(divisible4 '(12 5 13))
=> #f
```

Answer (score 0):

Named let recursion may be more easy to understand:

```
(define (div4 L)
  (let loop ((ll L))                       ; set up recursion and initial value; 
    (cond
      [(empty? ll)                     #t] ; if full list tested, return true;
      [(not(= 0 (modulo (car ll) 4)))  #f] ; if first item is not divisible, return false; 
      [else              (loop (rest ll))] ; else goto rest of list;
      )))
```